# Spring boot : MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to connect my spring boot application with MySQL server.

I have followed the documentation properly but still, I'm getting some issue in connection
Following exception is throwing every time

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
```

Comment: Is your mysql server up and running?

Comment: Are you able to connect to your mysql server using workbench or any other source apart from your application?

Comment: I'm able to connect with MySQL server through workbench eve.

Answer (score 4):

In order for me to get around this error I have to log into MySql with the username & password stored in my application.properties file using MySql Workbench.  After doing so the error no longer occurs. This only happens when trying to Run my spring boot project after restarting MySql server.

UPDATE: Adding "&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true" to my spring.datasource.url in the application.properties file solved the problem. I figured this out after I noticed another error in the logs: "MySQL Public Key Retrieval is not allowed"

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true

Answer (score 1):

First of all restart MySQL server and retry again...
If it is not...

Did you add `application.properties` details and JPA, MySQL dependency?
Please Could you show `pom.xml` file and `application.properties` file.

appication.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/JSP/ #jsp file path
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

#Hibernate
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

#JPA
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
     <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Thank you...!

Comment: I have done restarting the server and my application.properties and pom.xml matches the same.